# Combine XSLT select condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to combine two select condition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <catalog>
                <xsl:for-each select="offer[contains(
             translate(name, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
             'test')]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
             </xsl:for-each>
       </catalog>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Example:

```
<catalog>   
<offer>
<name>test 1</name>
<delivery>1</delivery>
</offer>

<offer>
<name>test 2</name>
<delivery>2</delivery>
</offer>
</catalog>
```

I tried to filter more the output by `offer[delivery='1']`, without success. The desidered output is:

```
<catalog>  
    <offer>
    <name>test 1</name>
    <delivery>1</delivery>
    </offer>
</catalog>
```

http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="offer[contains(translate(name, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'test') and delivery='1']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="offer[contains(translate(name, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'test')][delivery='1']"/>
```

would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Super, thank you. I think I tried earlier something like this, but I had somewhere a typo.